# saving point type data to pg server

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a function in postgres that inserts data to a table, and one of the columns is of type `point`.

I don't know how to save my gotten data to an acceptable form for the function to save my data.

The problematic code in question is :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION db."setMessage"(eml text, msg text, lat text, lng text)

...

INSERT INTO 
    db.messages 
VALUES 
    (DEFAULT, 
     id, 
     $2, 
     DEFAULT, 
     ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($3::float, $4::float), 4326)
    );
```

The error received when i call the function is:

```
ERROR: function st_makepoint(double precision, double precision) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Context: PL/pgSQL function "setMessage" line 9 at SQL statement
```

I have tries to save the point in string format (`'POINT(12.22343 64.22233)'`), tried not casting the st_makepoint arguments, and inserting without the outer function (`ST_SetSRID`).

could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**SOLUTION:**

So the method of success was following this [link](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS21UbuntuPGSQL93Apt) to get the needed libraries. after that i created the required extensions, and now i have access to the desired functions.

Comment: Looks like PostGIS isn't installed. What's the output of `\df ST_MakePoint` ?

Comment: yer the output is 0 rows. where do i install PostGIS?

Comment: I've tried `apt-get install postgis` but it returned some font packages (dejavu)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To install PostGIS, follow the instructions for your operating system at https://postgis.net/install.

Then, to enable it on your db you can do `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` from psql or PGAdmin.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, that postgres didn't find the function `st_makepoint` even though postgis extension was installed and I used the correct types for arguments. It turned out that the search path did not contain postgis.
Solution was: `alter database my_db set search_path = my_schema, public, postgis;` 
Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to re-install `postgis` extension and have tried many soluations but did not work for me.

I just edit my query and put `extensions` keyword before functions name like this:

```
INSERT INTO 
db.messages 
VALUES 
(DEFAULT, 
 id, 
 $2, 
 DEFAULT, 
 extensions.ST_SetSRID(extensions.ST_MakePoint($3::float, $4::float), 4326)
);
```

That worked for me.